# How can I hide files on desktop

Tags: pi-2

I have lots of stuff in one folder and I want my Desktop to be clean. Is their a way I can still have the folder that has all my stuff in but not have it on my desktop or USB. I still want to easily access the folder but not on my desktop.
Can someone help me or is this impossible?

Comment: If you don't want files on your desktop, put them some place else. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can move it to your Documents folder in the File Manager or you can use MV on a command line.

Hope this helps!

cheers

wayjo

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the Desktop you are using.

If the directory name starts with a `.` it may not be displayed.

So if the directory is called `fred` rename it `.fred`

Comment: uhhhh im using LXDE

Comment: I don't use a screen on the Pi and have no idea if naming the directory with an initial dot will work or not with LXDE.

Answer (score 0):

So if the file/folder is in the home folder, I think you have to do it in terminal. On desktop you can do it by right clicking it, rename, and rename it with a . Before the name.

(I go from Programs to .Programs)

In terminal it's a bit more complicated.

You have to do:

sudo mv /home/[yourusername]/[yourfile/folder] /home/[yourusername]/.fileorfolderhere

don't worry. I had the same question once.